# Unit testing DAL that requires authenticated user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-identity

Essentially, what I am trying to do is test some action as if a particular user is signed in and doing it. I have an interface that I implement on entities that required auditing as such

```
public interface IAuditableEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    string CreatedById{ get; set; }

    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    string UpdatedById { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC project, I've overwritten the `SaveChanges()` function in order to automatically fill in the fields above:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditableEntity
                && (x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added || x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {
            IAuditableEntity entity = entry.Entity as IAuditableEntity;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                var identityName = (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CreatedById = identityName;
                    entity.CreatedDate = now;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedById).IsModified = false;
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                }

                entity.UpdatedById = identityName;
                entity.UpdatedDate = now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This works perfectly in all cases, as you are required to sign into the application before any `IAuditableEntity` entity is modified. However, I am unable to figure out how to unit test this.

It seems reasonable to think that I should call my sign in method and things should work from there. My sign in method is essentially:

```
var ctx = this.Request.GetOwinContext();
ctx.SignIn(...)
```

Unfortunately, within the test project, there is no Request object. How do I simulate a `Request` within the scope of a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set value of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with instance of `ClaimsPrincipal` inside Unit test.

You don't need to setup fake `HttpRequest`, as you are using `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` directly.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I guess I just had one of the "duh" moments. However, I want to believe that there is a better method of achieving the desired result. It seems sort of hacky... Then again, unit testing sort of feels like that pretty often.

Comment: Nothing "hacky" there. MVC authentication doe's exactly the same under the hood (look up the sources).

Comment: The better way is to inject some sort of custom `ISecurityWrapper` to your UnitOfWork, and call it inside `SaveChanges()`.